# prestapyt can't upload new product

Tags: php, python, database, prestashop

I'm trying to create a script to add products to prestashop, through Python.

I'm using prestapyt library; I can read files, I can get template for new file but I cannot upload a new file. This is what I have:

```
from prestapyt import PrestaShopWebServiceError
from prestapyt import PrestaShopWebService
from prestapyt import PrestaShopWebServiceDict

DEBUG = 'true'
PS_SHOP_PATH = MYPATH
PS_WS_AUTH_KEY = MYKEY

prestashop = PrestaShopWebServiceDict(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG)
myproducts = prestashop.search('products');
addNewProduct(prestashop)
```

where

```
def addNewProduct(prestashop):
    blank_product = prestashop.get('products', options={'schema': 'blank'});
    pprint(blank_product)
    blank_product.update({'active': '1',
                 'additional_shipping_cost': '',
                 'advanced_stock_management': '',
                 'description': {'language': {'attrs': {'id': '2'}, 'value': 'DESCRIPTION!!!'}},
                 'description_short': {'language': {'attrs': {'id': '2'},
                                                    'value': 'SHORT DESCRIPTION!!!'}},
                 'id': '23',
                 'id_category_default': '2',
                 'name': {'language': {'attrs': {'id': '2'}, 'value': 'NAME'}},
                 'new': '1',
                 'price': '23',
                 'reference': 'MYREF',
                 'show_price': '1',
                 'width': ''})
        prestashop.add('products', blank_product)
```

When run this scrip I get the following:

> Execute url: MYPATH/api/products / method: POST Response code: 400
>
> Response headers:
>
> {'status': '400', 'psws-version': '1.6.1.6',
>   'x-powered-by': 'PrestaShop Webservice', 'transfer-encoding':
>   'chunked', 'set-cookie':
>   'PrestaShop-a0d2999cb4d9d838ea9bbca3cf8a7a22=gv2rmNYce013aHwM2TQ7718d8sl%2BCmTtT1hO7pqS6ItiGKUPTa%2FGUwpTprJh9pihDKJbQNq4DKb0N6SYqC5nxBM4Q%2F1AFCrubceV8yPEcMo%3D000079;
>   expires=Tue, 27-Sep-2016 21:15:16 GMT; Max-Age=1728000;
>   path=MYPATH; domain=SOMETHING; httponly',
>   'access-time': '1473282916', 'connection': 'close', 'execution-time':
>   '0.008', 'date': 'Wed, 07 Sep 2016 21:15:16 GMT', 'server': 'Apache',
>   'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=utf-8'}
>
> Response body:
>
> 'PrestaShop error: 400 Bad Request. Internal error. To see this error
>   please display the PHP errors.'

Any ideia?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I added what you suggested and this is what i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Script.py", line 24, in <module>
prestashop.edit('products', 1, address_data)

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 363, in edit
File "SAME", line 516,
in edit_with_url File "SAME", line 374,
in edit_with_url File "SAME", line 196,
in _execute File "SAME", line 127,
in _check_status_code

prestapyt.prestapyt.PrestaShopWebServiceError: 'PrestaShop error: 400 Bad Request. Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors.'
```

And it breaks here:

```
address_data = prestashop.get('products', 1)
address_data['active'] = '0'
prestashop.edit('products', 1, address_data) -> THIS LINE
```

any new ideas? Thank you!

Comment: *to see this error please display the PHP errors.* in config/defines.inc.php change to define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);

Comment: Try to enable `CGI mode for PHP` in PrestaShop backoffice. Change also the define like @SergiiP says.

Comment: Wait. Im running this on my laptop, as a Python script. Not as a php thingy. Should I still do that on the server?

Comment: you are getting error message from the server and error is happening there, so... yes, you need to enable debug mode on server or try to just check webserver logs

Answer (score 1):

You should do `blank_product['product'].update(...)` instead of `blank_product.update(...)`, the blank schema structure is: `{product: {...}}`.

In your edit when you use the `edit()` function you do not have to specify the product id, it is collected from the address_data fields (at least with the current version). But again you have to edit the fields this way: `address_data['product]['active']` = '0'

Hope this helps.